# How to animate an array of UIViews with a completion block being called after all UIViews finished animating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I'm animating every UIView in an array and want to know, when all animations are finished. For example: I'm showing 10 UIViews on a ViewController with a simple scale animation and for every UIView a small delay. After all 10 animations finished, I would like to do another animation in the completion block.

How do I know when all animations are finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `UIView`s are delayed sequentially, the last one you queue will be the last one to finish. Just do your stuff in its completion block.

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
__block int finishedViews = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:... completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  if (++finishedViews == numberOfViews) {
    // do stuff.
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Let say you have in your `UIViewController` the property `NSArray *arrayOfViews` which contains the views you want to animate. What you want could be something like this :

```
-(void)animateTheViews
{
    __block int nbTerminated = 0;
    for(UIView *aView in arrayOfViews)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:/*duration time in seconds*/ 
         animations:^{
             //set here the changes for aView

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             nbTerminated++;
             if(nbTerminated==[arrayOfViews count])
             {
                 [self whatToDoWhenFinished];
             }
        }];
    }
}

-(void)whatToDoWhenFinished
{
    //some stuff
}
```

**EDIT**

*`__block` is needed for the variable `nbTerminated`*

Comment: Thanks zbMax, works like the solution from Ian below. There is only one little mistake, the nbTerminated variable needs __block declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using group of animations.Every UIView is using an animation. Each animation sends animationDidStart: and animationDidStop:finished: to its delegate. So you can run codes when every and all animations finish. Please take a look at animationgroup [enter link description here](http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/5080831421/core-animation-part-iv-grouping-animations)

Comment: it is the same animation for each view

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
typedef void (^VoidBlock)(void);
typedef void (^BoolBlock)(BOOL flag);
```

in class interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)VoidBlock animationBlock;
```

and to animate:

```
NSArray *views = @[];

NSMutableArray *mutableViews = [views mutableCopy];

BoolBlock completionBlock = ^(BOOL flag){
    [mutableViews removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//delay
        self.animationBlock();
    });
};

self.animationBlock = ^{
    UIView *view = mutableViews.firstObject;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        //animate view
    }completion:completionBlock];
};
self.animationBlock();
```

Comment: Sorry, your solution didn't work for me. Only one view was animated and in a loop :-/

Comment: in animateWithDuration you should animate just one view, which you get in UIView *view = mutableViews.firstObject;